# Change language for return value of weekdayname

Tags: vba, excel

I'm printing some weekdays to a spreadsheet using the [`weekdayname`-function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278600(v=office.15).aspx). This works fine, except that the weekdays are written in the local language (Norwegian), instead of in English as I want it to. Is there any way to specify what language the function returns its results it, or am I stuck making my own UDF?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(1,"[$-414]DDDD")
```

Returns `søndag` for WeekDay 1 for `Norwegian_Bokmal (414)`

For a complete list of ID's see the link [List of Language Packs and Their Codes for Windows 2000 Domain Controllers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324097)

In case that link ever dies, here is the complete list

```
Locale/language              Language ID in hexadecimal
-------------------------------------------------------
Afrikaans                    436
Albanian                     041c
Arabic_Saudi_Arabia          401
Arabic_Iraq                  801
Arabic_Egypt                 0c01
Arabic_Libya                 1001
Arabic_Algeria               1401
Arabic_Morocco               1801
Arabic_Tunisia               1c01
Arabic_Oman                  2001
Arabic_Yemen                 2401
Arabic_Syria                 2801
Arabic_Jordan                2c01
Arabic_Lebanon 3             001
Arabic_Kuwait                3401
Arabic_UAE                   3801
Arabic_Bahrain               3c01
Arabic_Qatar                 4001
Armenian                     042b
Azeri_Latin                  042c
Azeri_Cyrillic               082c
Basque                       042d
Belarusian                   423
Bulgarian                    402
Catalan                      403
Chinese_Taiwan               404
Chinese_PRC                  804
Chinese_Hong_Kong            0c04
Chinese_Singapore            1004
Chinese_Macau                1404
Croatian                     041a
Czech                        405
Danish                       406
Dutch_Standard               413
Dutch_Belgian                813
English_United_States        409
English_United_Kingdom       809
English_Australian           0c09
English_Canadian             1009
English_New_Zealand          1409
English_Irish                1809
English_South_Africa         1c09
English_Jamaica              2009
English_Caribbean            2409
English_Belize               2809
English_Trinidad             2c09
English_Zimbabwe             3009
English_Philippines          3409
Estonian                     425
Faeroese                     438
Farsi                        429
Finnish                      040b
French_Standard              040c
French_Belgian               080c
French_Canadian              0c0c
French_Swiss                 100c
French_Luxembourg            140c
French_Monaco                180c
Georgian                     437
German_Standard              407
German_Swiss                 807
German_Austrian              0c07
German_Luxembourg            1007
German_Liechtenstein         1407
Greek                        408
Hebrew                       040d
Hindi                        439
Hungarian                    040e
Icelandic                    040f
Indonesian                   421
Italian_Standard             410
Italian_Swiss                810
Japanese                     411
Kazakh                       043f
Konkani                      457
Korean                       412
Latvian                      426
Lithuanian                   427
FYRO Macedonian              042f
Malay_Malaysia               043e
Malay_Brunei_Darussalam      083e
Marathi                      044e
Norwegian_Bokmal             414
Norwegian_Nynorsk            814
Polish                       415
Portuguese_Brazilian         416
Portuguese_Standard          816
Romanian                     418
Russian                      419
Sanskrit                     044f
Serbian_Latin                081a
Serbian_Cyrillic             0c1a
Slovak                       041b
Slovenian                    424
Spanish_Traditional_Sort     040a
Spanish_Mexican              080a
Spanish_Modern_Sort          0c0a
Spanish_Guatemala            100a
Spanish_Costa_Rica           140a
Spanish_Panama               180a
Spanish_Dominican_Republic   1c0a
Spanish_Venezuela            200a
Spanish_Colombia             240a
Spanish_Peru                 280a
Spanish_Argentina            2c0a
Spanish_Ecuador              300a
Spanish_Chile                340a
Spanish_Uruguay              380a
Spanish_Paraguay             3c0a
Spanish_Bolivia              400a
Spanish_El_Salvador          440a
Spanish_Honduras             480a
Spanish_Nicaragua            4c0a
Spanish_Puerto_Rico          500a
Swahili                      441
Swedish                      041d
Swedish_Finland              081d
Tamil                        449
Tatar                        444
Thai                         041e
Turkish                      041f
Ukrainian                    422
Urdu                         420
Uzbek_Latin                  443
Uzbek_Cyrillic               843
Vietnamese                   042a
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Do you know what happens if a user doesn't have the correct language pack installed though?

Comment: It probably won't be a problem at any rate.